# LiquiBase stored procedure creation failing

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc, liquibase

I am trying to create a stored procedure on my database through LiquiBase. I've tried using the `endDelimiter` tag in the changeset as well and nothing seems to be working here.

The changelog is as follows:

```
    <changeSet id="create-proc" context="common" author="adamstark" failOnError="true" runOnChange="true">
    <sqlFile path="../stored_procs/proc.sql"
             relativeToChangelogFile="true"
             splitStatements="false"/>
    <rollback>
        DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `proc`;
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

The SQL is as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE db$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc`()
  BEGIN
    Query 1
    Query 2
  END $$
```

I've verified that I can run the create procedure sql from a MySQL client, however I keep getting errors from liquibase saying the following:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DELIMITER $$

As I stated earlier I tried using the `endDelimiter` property, and my sql statement just immediately fails at the beginning of the query regardless of if I have the `DELIMITER $$` line.

Comment: Have you tried leaving out `DELIMITER $$`, and `USE db$$` (you should **not** use `use ..` when using JDBC) and leaving out `$$` (and permutations thereof combined with setting or not setting `endDelimiter`)? Also if used, `DELIMITER $$` should be `DELIMITER $$;`!

Comment: Have you tried the solution posted for this question on [create-function-from-sql-script-by-liquibase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34712347/create-function-from-sql-script-by-liquibase)